# How to optimize fileiterator (to avoid timeout) in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am hitting the Google Scripts 6-minute timeout. The script is running through quite a few folders and subfolders. I am hoping that there is either (or both):

1. A way to optimize the script to more efficiently/intelligently run through the dataset/iterators?
2. A way to use a getContinuationToken()

Any help would be much appreciated!

I have tried to limit the number of folders/subfolders the script runs through. Even on a 'minimal' run, it times out. And FYI, my goal is to:

1. make a copy of files that are NOT owned by 'me'...
2. change the name of the original file (that was not owned by me) to be 'delete'

Here is the code:

```
FOLDERS = ["0B4FiuEqe8ftGb2lSbjJzakJDNWs"]; /*, "0B4FiuEqe8ftGN2YxZFU5RlhMSDQ", "0B4FiuEqe8ftGN2YxZFU5RlhMSDQ", "1D_1u_KwcLOsBuKyQ7NCsKDd8DB5JwOn6"];*/


function copyNonOwnedFiles() {
var arr = FOLDERS

for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

var folderTOP = DriveApp.getFolderById(arr[j]);

var folders = folderTOP.getFolders();
var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

//RUN #1 = this runs through all of the subfolders
//iterator 1
while (folders.hasNext()) {
var folder = folders.next();

//get all files within these folders 
var files = folder.getFiles();

//iterator 2 
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();

var Owner = file.getOwner().getEmail();

if( Owner !== me ){ 
var name = file.getName(); 
file.makeCopy(name);
file.setName('delete'); 
}

}
}

//RUN #2 = this runs through the parent folder
var files2 = folderTOP.getFiles();

//iterator 2 
while (files2.hasNext()) {
var file2 = files2.next();

var Owner = file2.getOwner().getEmail();

if( Owner !== me ){ 
var name2 = file2.getName(); 
file2.makeCopy(name2);
file2.setName('delete'); 
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. Can I ask you about the total number of files and the total number of folders? About this, just a round about number is ok. 2. In your script, it seems that the files of `NOT owned by 'me'` are copied to the root folder. Is this correct? Are you required to create the copied files to the specific folder?

Comment: Hey Tanaike, sorry if I didn't provide enough detail. This is my first time posting! 1. There are a LOT of files, across a LOT of folders. I would guess in the high hundreds (ex: 700-800). That said, the first few runs of this will be much bigger than subsequent runs (after all non-owned files have been copied). 2. files not owned by me are copied to wherever they were originally... not the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who has this same question or a similar one... I found that it was much faster/easier/less resource intensive to use a search than a file iterator

```
dataSheetName = "List";

function onOpen(){
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('List Files', 'ListFiles')
      .addSeparator()
      .addToUi();
}

function ListFiles() {

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var dataSheet = sheet.getSheetByName(dataSheetName);

   // Clear Sheet
   var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow > 0) {
   dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, dataSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  }
  dataSheet.getRange("E2").setValue("Process Started at: " + new Date());
  Logger.log("Start: " + new Date());
//   var row = ['File Name', 'File Id'];
   var row = ['File Name', 'File Id'];
   var data = [];
   data.push(row);
  // Find files modified in the last 24 hours

  var totalDays = 30;

  var today     = new Date();
  var oneDayAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - totalDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);  
  var startTime = oneDayAgo.toISOString();

  // The magic search expression
  var search = '(trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > "' + startTime + '") and not (title contains \'DELETE\') and not (\'me\' in owners) ';
  // var search = "(mimeType='image/jpeg') and not (title contains 'DELETE') ";
  //  var search = " not ('me' in owners) and not (title contains 'DELETE') ";
  //  var search = " not ('me' in owners) ";
  //var search = 'sharedWithMe';
  // 'me' in owners
  var i = 1;
  var files  = DriveApp.searchFiles(search);
  Logger.log("2: " + new Date());
  dataSheet.getRange("E3").setValue("Search Completed at: " + new Date());

//  while (files.hasNext() && (i < 10000) {
  while (files.hasNext() ) {
     var file = files.next();
    try {
//    data.push([file.getName(),file.getId()]); 
    data.push([file.getName(), file.getId()]); 
    }
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log(file.getName());
    }
 //   i += i;

  }
   // Write data
   var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, row.length);
   dataRange.setValues(data);
  Logger.log("3: " + new Date());
    dataSheet.getRange("E4").setValue("List Completed at: " + new Date());


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This script will find the files owned by the active user, in the folders with the listed ids and display them on a modeless dialog.  This script will probably need to utilize lock service for multiple simultaneous users.

```
var myFiles=[];
var ids=["0B4FiuEqe8ftGb2lSbjJzakJDNWs", "0B4FiuEqe8ftGN2YxZFU5RlhMSDQ", "0B4FiuEqe8ftGN2YxZFU5RlhMSDQ", "1D_1u_KwcLOsBuKyQ7NCsKDd8DB5JwOn6"];
var me='';

function getMyFiles() {
  myFiles=[];
  me=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
    getFnF(DriveApp.getFolderById(ids[i]));
  }
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Item</th><th>Name</th><th>Url</th></tr>";
  for(var i=0;i<myFiles.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><a href="%s" target="_blank">Link</a></td></tr>',i+1,myFiles[i].name,myFiles[i].url);
  }
  html+='</table><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var title=Utilities.formatString('Files Owned by: %s',me);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, title)
}

function getFnF(folder) {
  var folder= folder || DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files=folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    if(file.getOwner().getEmail()==me) {
      myFiles.push({name:file.getName(),url:file.getUrl()});
    }
  }
  var subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for the response! This hit the max execution time as well. I was supposed to run them both as one function, correct? Also, I think the prompt that this sends is cool... but my goal is to 1) make a copy of files that are NOT owned by 'me'... and then 2) change the name of the original file (that was not owned by me) to be 'delete'

Comment: Just run getMyFiles and it calls getFnf().  So I suppose you will have to run it in batches (i.e.) one folder at a time and hope that works.  There must be a lot files in there.

Comment: You can take a look at the execution log and see if removing the dialog portion of the script might get you your answer and then just `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(myFiles));`

Comment: oh that's cool. I have not seen a script run a script like that. What is the reason for all the html creation? Does that help the script determine who owns the files? How would I then run the copy/name change? Unfortunately, the way my folder structure is set up, it would be really difficult to do it 'one-at-a-time'. Is there a way to use a continuation token or something similar?

Comment: It's just creating a dialog to view the data.  But if you have a lot of lines I suppose it could take a long time.